# How to wait for an answer of a API GET?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm having a problem related with the velocity of protractor.

When I click on a link, a new window must open with a table that willl be filled by a GET event.

It seems that protracor is too fast and doesn´t wait for the get answer. 
I use sleep but I didn’t solve it.

This issue only happens with automatic test.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two solutions:

1. You can wait for visibility a specific element in DOM (eg. cell with a data) using ExpectedConditions:  http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions
2. You can use `request` library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and call the endpoint until you get desired response.